# Can we run the SonarQube for Multiple Project?

Tags: sonarqube

Am able to run the SonarQube for the One Project and am getting the Report in the Dashboard. But i have 50 Source projects to run at a time to get a Global Result. Is it Possible to run the sonar for multiple projects at a time. If yes what are the configurations need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run SonarQube analysis one by one on each project, there's no other way.

Comment: Is there any way to combine all the results

Comment: Yes, using the Views plugin: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/